# Inconsistency in designing screen with storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uistoryboard

I am using `Xcode 6.3` to develop an app using size classes. My initial settings - `ViewController` size - `4.7 inch` (Focus on design for iPhone 6). After setting up the elements and constraints, when run in the device/simulator (iPhone 6), the UI elements shows scaled up, for example : A UIView of height 65 points is shown of about 78 points on the device and similarly all the elements are bigger and the spacing is quite large from what defined in the `storyboard`.

After too much struggle, I found out that its not a matter of `ViewController` settings or constraints, because I created another project with same settings and it works as expected. I've tried enabling/disabling size classes, created new storyboard for testing (in the same project) but it too showed scaled up elements.

How can I fix this?